# JAVA: conditioning String to comboBox items, it is possible?

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I am trying to make an `if` conditional statement that will compare my textfield `FillUnitTextTag` to jcombobox `cmbBox_PurchsUnit`'s items so that, no redundant items will be added to the combobox.

my `FillUnitTextTag` textfield is the field were I can add item(s) to the comboBox `cmbBox_PurchsUnit` but it also keeps the existing one(intentional).

How may I get rid of it?

### here's my actual code:

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if(FillUnitTextTag.getText().equals(cmbBox_PurchsUnit.getSelectedIndex())){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item is already in the combobox");
    } else {
        int p = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, FillUnitTextTag.getText()+" will be added to units.\n"
            + "Do want to continue?","", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if(p==0){
            cmbBox_PurchsUnit.addItem(FillUnitTextTag.getText());
            cmbBox_PurchsUnit.setSelectedItem(FillUnitTextTag.getText());
            UnitPopUp.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Best if you could create and post an [mcve] so we can see exactly what you're trying to do, and why your code is not working.

Comment: If you want to simply add an items if they are not already in the combo box, simply iterate through your combobox items and if none match your item to be added, add it.

Comment: @River That's my problem.. T.T
How may I do that.?? i'd try many times as what I can do but still sucks!

Comment: You need to **loop** through the contents of the JComboBox -- that means a for loop -- where is your for loop?

Comment: @HovercraftFullofEels
for loop? i'm sorry but, how's it working with my code? may I ask you to show me please?

Comment: Please clarify: do you not know how to use a for loop? ... or why it is needed for this to work?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes, but only basics.. maybe I will understand your answer someday. it takes a couple of days for me to get your point. its our project and I'm trying to give my best just to finish this work.

Comment: You'll be much better off trying to figure out the actual code for yourself and not asking us to do it for you. Try to implement what I've suggested, and if it works, great. If not, show what you've tried by editing your question and posting your latest code. I'm betting that you're selling yourself short, that you really can do it based on this information. Prove me right.

Comment: Please check changes to code formatting made in your question. Carefully formatting your code so that all code inner code blocks are indented and that all code code blocks on the same level are indeted the same amount make it easier for others to understand your code -- a worthy goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Get the JComboBox's model via its `getModel()` method,
- then loop through the model using a for loop comparing Strings in the model vs the String to add.
- The model has a `getSize()` method that tells you how many times to loop
- And it has a `getElementAt(int index)` method that allows you to get each item in the model for comparison.

In pseudocode (since again, you're better off writing your own code):

```
set a boolean variable, okToAdd to true
Get your combo box's model by calling getModel() on it.  
create a for loop that loops from 0 to the size of the model, which you get by calling getSize()  
    in the loop get each item from the model via getElementAt(int index)
    compare the item to the String of interest via the equals(...) method
    If they match then change okToAdd to false  
end of for loop.
If okToAdd is true, add String to the combo box's model
```

Comment: This is exactly what I meant, just do this instead of your single `if` statement. Then if any of your comparisons return true, print your message.

Comment: ugh*! Thank you but I really cant do it... its hard for me as a beginner to understand. thanks a lot by the way. :-(

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'd also recommend "leaving the loop on a match" (e.g. `break`)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
ComboBoxModel cmbBoxmodel = cmbBox_PurchsUnit.getModel();
        cmbBoxmodel.getSize();
        for(int dis=0;dis<=cmbBoxmodel.getSize();dis++){

        cmbBoxmodel.getElementAt(dis);
        }
```

Comment: That looks like it works fine. Except you should do `dis <` instead of `dis <=` to avoid out of bounds indexes. Now just implement the comparison! (And you should really do testing at the bottom of your question or something instead of in this answer)